# Revert archived files to specified locations like Downloads, Documents and Desktop

Tags: shortcut, file, productivity, document-management

I'm working on two projects, let's call them Project1 and Project2.
This week I'll be working on Project1.
The files of Project1 on which I'll be working are stored at different place on my PC - Downloads, Documents and Desktop.

The next week I'll be switching over to Project2, Project1 will be incomplete.
Now I don't want both projects to mess up so I want to do something like move the Project1 files to a different place under 3 different alias Downloads, Documents and Desktop.

Then when I finish my Project2, I want my Project1 files to move to their original locations with some shortcut keys or a single command.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use a separate user for each project.

Another way is to not use the standard settings and put all of one project under the same directory. This does mean that you need to treat Downloads as a temporary location, when you download you then move it to a directory you use.

If these do not suit your problem I think you need to expand how things could mess up - also how are they backed up - if you go through this in detail then I think you will see you need to change your working practice